# Data fetching using Google Analytics API v4

Tags: java, google-analytics-api

It may be weird to ask this but still I need some insights on this. I have to use Google Analytics API v4 API for data fetching but the code is returning compilation error even after importing and adding all the required jars in it's class-path.

The following are the classes which are unable to resolve compilation error :

```
AnalyticsreportingScopes
Analyticsreporting
ColumnHeader
DateRange
DateRangeValues
Dimension
GetReportsRequest
GetReportsResponse
Metric
MetricHeaderEntry
Report
ReportRequest
ReportRow
```

I have added `google-api-services-analyticsreporting-v4-rev7-1.22.0.jar` for these classes in the class-path. 
Please help me out tackling this so that I can proceed further in achieving my objective.

Comment: Could you please post more details on how you're building your project. From the info you provide, it is really difficult to help, at least for me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm building the project using Eclipse IDE. I have downloaded all the required jars from ' Analytics Reporting API V4 Java Client library'. I have created a new folder 'libs' in my project. I copied all the required jars in this folder and after this I added these jars to the class-path using 'Build Path'. I'm trying the example from this link : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm able to remove the compilation errors. I simply removed all the 'import' statements from the beginning of the codes and resolved 'import' by selecting every class under 'red line'. It was quite weird behaviour by thanks to Eclipse IDE. I'm done with resolving compiling errors.
Now, I can proceed to other important aspects of the process I have to achieve. Thanks to everyone who looked into this.